# Where is the property that do not conform to the protocol goes?

Tags: swift, initialization, protocols

`Teacher` & `TeamMate` are two protocols. The class `Coach` conforms to those protocols.

```
protocol Teacher {
    var firstName: String { get }
    var lastName: String { get }
    var title: String { get }
}

protocol TeamMate {
    var firstName: String { get }
    func role()
}

class Coach: Teacher, TeamMate {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var title: String

    func role() {
        print("coach the team")
    } 

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, title: String){
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.title = title
    }
}

var member: TeamMate = Coach(firstName: "Izumi", lastName: "Yakuza", title: "LA Coach")
```

I've created a variable named `member` of type `coach` meanwhile it conforms to the `TeamMate` type (***Please correct me if the description is not accurate***)

I need to initialise all the properties defined in the `Coach` class when I create the `member` object. I.e.`(firstName: "Izumi", lastName: "Yakuza", title: "LA Coach")`. However, in the end, there is only one property `firstName` and one method `role()` inside the `member` instance.

[image]

**Question:** How the properties (`lastName: "Yakuza", title: "LA Coach"`) were processed? Is that they were created firstly and then cut away or just hidden?

Thanks a lot for your kind help and time.

Comment: You're cutting away this type information when you upcast to `TeamMate` (`member : TeamMate`), as that protocol only defines `firstName` and `role()`. Is there a reason `member` can't simply be of type `Coach`? Upcasting will always lose type information, so you shouldn't do it unless you need to.

Comment: @originaluser2 no, not a particular reason. This is not a project code. I was created for self-learning. **Upcasting will always lose type information** is the exact answer I'm looking for. I don't even know this process is named **Upcasting**. Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've created a variable named member of type coach meanwhile it conforms to the TeamMate type

```
var member: TeamMate = Coach(firstName: "Izumi", lastName: "Yakuza", title: "LA Coach")
```

I suspect this line of code isn't doing what you think it's doing. Your `member` variable isn't of type `Coach`, you've upcast to the abstract type `TeamMate` (a protocol which `Coach` conforms to). Therefore when using your variable, you can only access members that `TeamMate` defines (`firstName` and `role()`) – which is the exact behaviour you're seeing.

Unless you need to you shouldn't upcast your variables, as upcasting loses type information. In most cases, you should just let Swift infer the correct type for you. In your case `member` should almost certainly be of type `Coach` (you can always freely pass it to anything expecting a `TeamMate`, as `Coach` conforms to this protocol).

Therefore, you just want to drop the explicit type annotation:

```
var member = Coach(firstName: "Izumi", lastName: "Yakuza", title: "LA Coach")
```

You should also make it a `let` constant if you don't plan on mutating it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. **Unless you need to you shouldn't upcast your variables.**   Good to known that!

Comment: @SLN Happy to help :) Upcasting can be useful if you plan on mixing different types together that conform to a common protocol (i.e an array of `TeamMate`), but it's rarely useful for single variables as you can always pass the more specific type to something that expects a type that it conforms to (or inherits from).